# What is in the A320 Smoke and Fume checklist?

Tags: emergency, airbus-a320, checklist

What does the "Smoke and Fume Checklist" for the Airbus 320 series look like?

Is it a printed item or is it on the ECAM screen?

Comment: [Related](https://hursts.org.uk/airbus-nonnormal/html/ch06.html#smoke-fumes). The answer is both. Found in QRH and on the ECAM. More [from Airbus](https://leehamnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/smokeprocedures.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I'm resuming this old question because no answer was given.

It depends on where the smoke is detected (if automatically detected). The following abnormal procedures exist:

1. **SMOKE** FWD(AFT) CARGO SMOKE
2. **SMOKE** LAVATORY SMOKE
3. **AVIONICS SMOKE**
4. SMOKE/FUMES/AVNCS SMOKE + REMOVAL OF SMOKE/FUMES

The checklists 1, 2, 3 have the corresponding ECAM message automatically triggered when smoke is detected, while the checklist 4 is a long checklist which guides the pilot in identifying the source of the smoke and taking the necessary actions (and has no corresponding ECAM message).

Checklist 1 instructs the pilots to close the air isolation valve and discharge the agent(s).

Checklist 2 instructs the pilots to <s>punch the guy smoking in the toilette</s> contact the cabin crew.

Checklist 3 instructs the pilots to perform the relevant part of Checklist 4.